# SQL How to map value if exists?

Tags: sql

I have `table_1` with some values

```
|id|value|
----------
|1|val1|
|2|val2|
|3|val3|
|4|val4|
```

and `table_2` for mappings

```
|key|value|
-----------
|val2|OtherValue|
|val3|SomeValue|
```

and I need a `select` result like:

```
|id|value|
---------
1|val1
2|OtherValue
3|SomeValue
4|val4
```

I can do something like:

```
select t1.id, t1.value from table_1 t1 join table2 t2 on t2.value = t1.value
```

But it doesn't work
Thanks

Comment: What type of database?

Comment: If your labels are correct, I think you want to do `join table2 t2 on t2.key = t1.value`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have various options.
The most important thing here is that what you are doing is a `LEFT JOIN`.

A `LEFT JOIN` works by including the rows on the left-hand table even when the corresponding ones are missing from the right-hand table. In other words, if you were to select all rows from the dataset you provided by doing a `LEFT JOIN` selecting all columns, you would obtain:

```
|table_1 |   table_2       |
|id|value|   key|value     |
| 1| val1|<null>|<null>    |
| 2| val2|  val2|OtherValue|
| 3| val3|  val3|SomeValue |
| 4| val4|<null>|<null>    |
```

At this point, it's just a matter of tweaking the columns you are selecting and, in particular, how data is extracted from the key and value columns. What you want to say is
`if there is something in table_2.value use it, otherwise use table_1.value`.

This can be achieved in various ways, some are standard SQL and some are platform-dependent.

Given the simple nature of the query I would use the standard SQL `COALESCE` function. If however the query was more complicated, you may need to resort to a `CASE` block (also standard).

Here follows the query using `COALESCE`.

```
SELECT
    table_1.id AS id,
    COALESCE(table_2.value, table_1.value) AS value
FROM
    table_1
    LEFT JOIN table_2 ON (table_1.value = table_2.key)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should `join` `table_1`'s `value` on `table_2`'s `key`.

```
SELECT
    t1.id
    ,CASE
        WHEN t2.value IS NULL THEN t1.value
        ELSE t2.value
    END AS value
FROM table_1 t1
LEFT JOIN table_2 t2
    ON t1.value = t2.key
```

Comment: that will get the join right, but he will still need something to get the right values if the entry doesn't exist in t2

Comment: Oh apologies @Kevin! I missed that part. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

You want to do a left join with an isnull on the values

```
select t1.id, isNull(t2.value,t1.value) 
from table_1 t1 left join table2 t2 
on t2.key= t1.value
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    t1.id,
    CASE
        WHEN t2.valueIS NULL THEN t1.value
        ELSE t2.value
    END AS value
FROM
    table_1 t1
    LEFT JOIN
        table2 t2
        ON t2.value= t1.value
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try below sql query:

```
    SELECT id, 
       CASE 
         WHEN t1.[value] = t2.[key] THEN t2.[value] 
         ELSE t1.[value] 
       END AS 'value' 
FROM   table_1 t1 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[table_2] t2 
                    ON t1.[value] = t2.[key]
```